# protected access type

Tags: java, subclass, access-specifier

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Java, what's the difference between public, default, protected, and private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

Why can't a subclass in one package access the protected member of it's superclass (in another package) by the reference of the superclass? I am struggling with this 
point. Please help me

```
package points;
public class Point {
  protected int x, y;
}

package threePoint;
import points.Point;
public class Point3d extends Point {
  protected int z;
  public void delta(Point p) {

    p.x += this.x;          // compile-time error: cannot access p.x
    p.y += this.y;          // compile-time error: cannot access p.y

  }
```

Answer (score 8):

A protected member can be accessed by the class, other classes in the package and implicitly by its subclasses. i.e., the subclass can access `x` from its own parent.

The fact that you are able to access `this.x` proves that `x` from the superclass is accessible. If `x` were private in the superclass, `this.x` would give an error.

When you say `p.x` you are trying to access some other instance's `x`, and not in its own hierarchy. This is not allowed outside the package.

Answer (score 1):

Because you reference the members of a *different* instance of `Point`. This is not allowed.

You can of course access the inherited members as you do with `this.x`.